# Como instanciar views de outro layout?

Tags: android

Tenho o layout `main` e o código que controla ele, esse layout tem um `Navigation Drawer` (a "barra deslizante" na esquerda) e deixei o layout do `Main Header` (a parte de cima do `Navigation Drawer` onde fica as informações do usuário) em outro arquivo. Tentei instanciar essas views pelo `FindViewById` da `MainActivity` achando que iria dar certo pois o `main_header` está incluso no layout do `main`, mas não funciona, depurei o código e vi que as variáveis que deviam ter aquela view do `main_header` estavam recebendo `null`, como se não fosse possível acessar elas dali, como posso instanciá-las?

(Estou fazendo o projeto em `Xamarin Android`, mas até agora o funcionamento me pareceu o mesmo comparado à `Java`, então se souber responder em `Java` ajuda também.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caso alguém precise da resposta futuramente também:
o `NavigationView` (onde você define o main header) tem um método chamado `getHeaderView()`, depois de instanciar o `NavigationView` você "guarda" o header dele em uma outra view e usa ela para instanciar.

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0)
TextView text = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```